# How to check if json inner field is EMPTY?

Tags: postgresql

One of the column ( called details ) in my table is of jsonb data type and have data format somthing like this:

```
{"media_height":"350", "media_height":"450", "media_alt":"", "file_name":"myfile.jpeg"}
```

This field I am taking in case when because I want to mark the records of missing alt text.

```
SELECT
            distinct ON ( p.property_name )
                        p.id, p.property_name,
                        CASE
                            WHEN mma.id IS NULL THEN 'Z'
                            WHEN mma.details->'media_alt'::TEXT IS NULL THEN 'NO'
                            ELSE 'YES' END as has_media_alt
            FROM properties p
            LEFT JOIN marketing_media_associations mma ON ( mma.reference_id = p.id ) 
            GROUP BY p.id, p.property_name , mma.details->'media_alt', mma.id
            ORDER BY p.property_name, has_media_alt ASC
```

The above query gives me accurate results for Z, but it never goes in NO block. What I am missing here?

Comment: The media_alt field is definitely not null in this example.  It is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is not the same as NULL, you probably want:

```
WHEN nullif(mma.details->>'media_alt', '') IS NULL THEN 'NO'
```

You don't need to cast to text, if you use `->>` which returns the value as `text` directly.